# windows server 2008 cannot connect to internet

Tags: windows-server-2008, internet

I am working in project to create local area network for school 
I created domain school.com and connected the clients with it and assign IP
the problem is windows server 2008 cannot connect to internet  even I connect the modem to switch 
the connection local only

IP address for server 192.168.5.2
subnet 255.255.255.0
default gateway 192.168.5.1

Answer (score 2):

Is your server a domain controller? If so, then you probably have dns installed and your nic is configured to use that Dns server. By default Your dns server will not resolve Internet IP addresses.

To fix this, open the dns server management app. Right-click on the server name and pick properties. Then you either need to configure your root hints or add a forwarder.

for root hints,  the easiest thing to do is to use the import option and enter the ip address of a public DNS  server like 8.8.8.8

however,  in a  small environment using a forwarder is better.  add your isp's  dns servers to the forwarders list or use some public ones like 8.8.8.8  and 8.8.4.4

Comment: yes, my server domain controller . I opened dns server management app , what should i do with root hints or add a forwarder ?

Comment: Don't mean to be offensive - but the above is fairly standard network admin stuff, are you really in the position to setup their whole domain?

Comment: I added more detail to my answer.

Comment: I am working in this project as final project for my college I will try your solution and I will tell you if it is work

Comment: I added the ip of router 192.168.1.254 and I add public dns ip 8.8.8.8 to forward list but still no internet