# Internet not available in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

There is a Windows Server SP2 machine in my office and it is not a domain server. No internet connection is possible in it from today.

First of all, I checked [windows server 2008 cannot connect to internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/488619/windows-server-2008-cannot-connect-to-internet) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821620/having-internet-connectivity-issues-in-windows-server-2008-r2 . These are not my issue

This system used to loose internet connection previously and a restarting was enough to solve it. But today restarting, troubleshooting or whatever I tried didn't solved this issue.

I searched a lot in Google, but found nothing helpful. I did a 'ipconfig /all' and this was the result
[image]

In this image it is written 'Tap Windows Adapter V9'. What is that ?

This is 'Network and Sharing Centre'

[image]

As you can see there is a 'Local Area Connection 4'. When internet connection was available there was one more 'Local Area Connection'.

Also I did 'ping' with 8.8.8.8 and with my router.Both was 100 % loss.

I only know this much to describe, because am not much familiar with Server editions. If you found this question as a stupid one don't ignore. Help me first and then do down-vote or delete... Help please.... If you want to know any more ask me. I will reply what ever I know.

Comment: You have neither a valid IP address nor a default gateway.  This suggests a failure among the following:  network card, cable, switch, DHCP.  Check all of these.

Answer (score 4):

You are getting an APIPA address (169.x.x.x), normally meaning that your DHCP server is unavailable and you are getting incorrect IP details

Normally for servers, you would assign them a static IP address

Also basic networking knowledge would also tell you that without a default gateway, you aint going to get out onto the internet.

Comment: Can you define it a little more ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with your network card, because your primary connection has "TAP-Windows Adapter V9" in description, which is usualy provided by openvpn for using a VPN.

Check your network card.

Try to uninstall any software you installed before you got this problem.